# Automatic internet connection on startup in OpenBSD?

Tags: wifi, openbsd, internet

I just installed the OpenBSD in my computer. I've learned how to connect to my wireless network using the following commands (even though I don't quite know what they mean):

```
ifconfig iwn0 nwid [network name] wpa wpapsk [password]
dhclient iwn0
```

I am looking for a way to connect just after the boot. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OpenBSD you set up networking by creating a file called /etc/hostname.iwn0 (or whatever else your interface is called).

Thus you should probably just add the following to your /etc/hostname.iwn0:

```
 dhcp nwid [network name] wpa wpapsk [password]
```

Comment: Read more in the [man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=hostname.if&sektion=5)