# Problem with WPA connection on OpenBSD

Tags: wifi, openbsd, wpa-supplicant

I have an OpenBSD 5.3 amd64 installed and Intel WiFi Link 1000 card which works with WEP but I obtain a strange message with WPA keys:

```
# sh /etc/netstart iwn0 
iwn0: no link ............. sleeping

# dhclient iwn0
iwn0: no link ............. sleeping
```

configuration :

```
# cat /etc/hostname.iwn0                                            
dhcp nwid Livebox-5dxx wpakey xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
# cat /etc/mygate
192.168.1.1 // Correct I check
```

Result with ifconfig :

```
# ifconfig iwn0
iwn0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
lladdr 74:e5:0b:c6:xx:xx
priority: 4
groups: wlan
media: IEEE802.11 autoselect (DS1 mode 11g)
status: no network
ieee80211: nwid Livebox-5dxx chan 6 bssid 00:19:70:a5:xx:xx 222dB wpakey 0x620f88c77fc3866ac2165966050980e5cc18f2a606c84b680c62xxxxxxxxxxxx wpaprotos wpa1,wpa2 wpaakms psk wpaciphers tkip,ccmp wpagroupcipher tkip
inet6 fe80::76e5:bff:fec6:d914%iwn0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x2
```

I would like to know how to debug this configuration.

Is it normal that my WPA key appear in hex with prefix `0x` in `ifconfig` output?

How do I ensure that my WPA key settings are correct?

Answer (score 1):

1 - You could follow this other answer to edit your `/etc/hostname.iwn0` and add the `wpapsk` parameter

[Automatic internet connection on startup in OpenBSD?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22313/automatic-internet-connection-on-startup-in-openbsd)

2 - The Hex key is calculated based on your network id, and wpa passphrase(wpa-psk). Try this site, is very usefull:

```
http://jorisvr.nl/wpapsk.html
```

Check if the Hex Key calculated on this site is the same provided by `ifconfig.` If not, additional debug could be needed

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing the `wpa` keyword in your `hostname.iwn0`.

You have:

```
dhcp nwid Livebox-5dxx wpakey xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I think it should be:

```
dhcp nwid Livebox-5dxx wpa wpakey xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

It's normal for it to report the wpakey as 0xabcdef.....  `ifconfig` allows you to specify a passphrase as a convenience to you.  It converts it into a hex string for you.

Comment: wpa is not needed if there is wpakey, it is written in the manpage. well i think you have compatibility problem. i have had problem with various APs which were used happily by Windows users. Have you tried to associate to different wpa AP?