# Centrino N-6300 OpenBSD 5.5 - No Link

Tags: wifi, openbsd

I have a Lenovo X230 with a Centrino N-6300 wifi card.
I cannot get wifi to work on it.
I did `fw_upgrade`
I can do a

```
ifconfig iwno scan
```

I have the list of Wifi networks around including mine.  However if I try to setup `/etc/hostname.iwn0`

```
nwid Livebox-XXXX
wpakey XXXXXXXXX
dhcp
```

then

```
sh /etc/netstart iwn0
```

I got:

```
No link: .............. sleeping
```

Same if I try:

```
ifconfig iwn0 nwid Livebox-XXXX wpakey XXXXXXXX
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Take a look at this topic: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78139/problem-with-wpa-connection-on-openbsd   ;)

Comment: @nwildner thanks for the heads up I already tried:
- http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78139/problem-with-wpa-connection-on-openbsd
- http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22313/automatic-internet-connection-on-startup-in-openbsd \\
No way to get a link ... I suppose it's N-6300 that is not supported (yet) but the weird thing is I can scan networks :| \\
Looking at the Hex key that must be generated form http://jorisvr.nl/wpapsk.html it is totally different ...

Comment: Yes it is - http://www.openbsd.org/47.html - It started being supported on OpenBSD 4.7. And it seems that you are using the latest version of this firmware - http://firmware.openbsd.org/firmware/5.5/

Comment: Well then where is the error/how can I debug this?

Comment: `dmesg| grep iwn` shows something?.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried today with OpenBSD 5.8 iso and it's working fine out of the box !
Thanks @nwilder for the help.